# Running a shell script can print all the output on a hyper terminal while running the corresponding python script can’t on an Ubuntu host terminal

Tags: python, printing, buffer

I used a Hyper terminal such as GTKTerm to run a shell script ./test.sh (whose shell commands act on a hardware board) and it displays ALL the desired outputs on GTKTerm screen, and then I converted ./test.sh to a python script and ran it on a host Ubuntu terminal via a UART port like below

```
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', baudrate=115200, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS, timeout=5) 

ser.write(b"./test.sh\n")
```

My question is – when the size of `./test.sh` becomes bigger and bigger, I can still observe the entire output on the GTKTerm terminal after running `./test.sh`, but running the converted python script (such as running `python3 test.py` or  `python3 test.py > test.txt`), can’t see the same **whole** output as running `./test.sh` on GTKTerm when the size of `./test.sh` reaches to a threshold value.

I tried to fix this issue using such as `python3 -u ...`, print function with flush argument, various flush commands related to UART, .... Unfortunately, I didn't solve this issue. Could anyone kindly tell me the reasons? Thank you!!

Comment: Thank you, @Barmar, for your kind edition! 
I'm adding additional python codes here (to be easier to understand my question). Hopefully I can get someone's help. 
`ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', baudrate=115200, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS, timeout=5)
ser.write(b"./test.sh\n") 
ser.flush()
lines = ser.readlines()
for line in lines:
    stripped_line = line.strip()
    ser.flush()
    print(stripped_line, flush=True)'

Comment: Don't try to put code in comments. If you want to clarify the question, use the Edit button. You can see how the code block was written in my edit, you can copy that styling.